# when i createElement in one function, when i getElementById it results in an error

Tags: javascript, html, function, getelementbyid, createelement

so this is my html code, now i know itd be easier just to code the elements into the html code, but i need to be able to create the element in one function, and modify it in another.
so this is mt html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tetris(test)</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleSheets/main.css">
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/jquery.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg id="container" width= "500" height= "650" style= "background-color: black" position= "relative">
      <div class= "grid"></div>
    </svg>

  </body>
</html>
```

this is my JS code:

```
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var count = 0;
var count2 = 1000000;

var elm = ""
function createShape1() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("container");
    var shape = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
    count++
        shape.id = "shape" + count;
        shape.className = "class";
        elm = document.getElementById("shape");
        console.log(elm);
        shape.style.width = "150px";
        shape.style.height = "50px";
        shape.style.fill = "purple";
        shape.style.y = "50px";
        shape.style.x = "150px"
        shape.style.position = "absolute"
        elem.append(shape);
    var shape2 = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
    count2++;
        shape2.id = "shape" + count2;
        shape2.style.fill = "purple";
        shape2.style.x = "200px";
        shape2.style.width = "50px";
        shape2.style.height  = "51px";
        elem.append(shape2);
};

window.onload = randShape;
function createShape2() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("container");
    var shape = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
    count++;
        shape.id = "shape" + count;
        console.log(shape.id)
        shape.style.width = "100px";
        shape.style.height = "100px";
        shape.style.fill = "red";
        shape.style.x = "200px"
        shape.style.position = "absolute"
        elem.append(shape);
};
function createShape3() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("container");
    var shape = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
    count++;
        shape.id = "shape" + count;
        console.log(shape.id)
        shape.style.width = "50px";
        shape.style.height = "200px";
        shape.style.fill = "blue";
        shape.style.x = "200px"
        shape.style.position = "absolute"
        elem.append(shape);
}
function createShape4() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("container");
    var shape = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
    count++;
        shape.id = "shape" + count;
        console.log(shape.id)
        shape.style.width = "100px";
        shape.style.height = "51px";
        shape.style.fill = "green";
        shape.style.x = "200px"
        shape.style.position = "absolute"
        elem.append(shape);
    var shape2 = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
    count2++;
        shape2.id = "shape" + count2;
        console.log(shape2.id)
        shape2.style.width = "100px";
        shape2.style.height = "50px";
        shape2.style.fill = "green";
        shape2.style.x = "150px"
        shape2.style.y = "50px"
        shape2.style.position = "absolute"
        elem.append(shape2);
}
function createShape5() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("container");
    var shape = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
    count++;
        shape.id = "shape" + count;
        console.log(shape.id)
        shape.style.width = "50px";
        shape.style.height = "150px";
        shape.style.fill = "orange";
        shape.style.x = "200px"
        shape.style.position = "absolute"
        elem.append(shape);
    var shape2 = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
        shape2.id = "shape" + count2;
        console.log(shape2.id)
        shape2.style.width = "51px";
        shape2.style.height = "50px";
        shape2.style.fill = "orange";
        shape2.style.x = "249px";
        shape2.style.position = "absolute";
        elem.append(shape2);
}
var shapes = [createShape1, createShape2, createShape3, createShape4, createShape5]
function randShape() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    shapes[x]();
    var shape = document.getElementById("shape" + count);
    var shape2 = document.getElementById("shape" + count2);
    console.log(shape2.style.x)
    console.log(shape.style.fill)
};
```

so it works for creatShape1(), createShape4(), and createShape5(), however when the randomShape function randomly selects createShape2() and createShape3() i get the error "cannot read property 'style' of null"

Comment: Those two functions are fine.  The error you're seeing is because you're not creating a second shape in `createShape2` or `createShape3` and you're trying to `console.log(shape2.style.x)` in `randShape`.

Comment: var shape2 = document.getElementById("shape" + count2); is not being created. that's why is null.

Comment: ok that makes sence. i just need to add an invisable shape, or an identical shape over the other. ok thanks that makes perfect sence.